# $SAS^{-1} = B$, $S,A \in \operatorname{Mat}_{3,3}(\mathbb{R})$ but $A$ has complex eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, orthogonality

Consider the following matrix $A \in \operatorname{Mat}_{3,3}(\mathbb{R})$:
$$A=\frac{1}{90}\left(\begin{array}{ccc} 66 & -18 \sqrt{6} & 30 \sqrt{2} \\6 \sqrt{6} & 72 & 30 \sqrt{3} \\-42 \sqrt{2} & -18 \sqrt{3} & 60\end{array}\right)$$

Determine an orthogonal matrix $S \in \operatorname{Mat}_{3,3}(\mathbb{R})$ such that the matrix $SAS^{-1}$ takes the form
$$SAS^{-1}=\left(\begin{array}{ccc} \pm 1 & 0 & 0 \\0 & \cos (\theta) & \sin (\theta) \\0 & -\sin (\theta) & \cos (\theta)\end{array}\right)$$
with a real number $\theta \in [0,2\pi[$.

I'm confused since $A \in \operatorname{Mat}_{3,3}(\mathbb{R})$ ($A$ is orthogonal) but the eigenvalues of $A$ are complex. Does this effect the existence of such an $S \in \operatorname{Mat}_{3,3}(\mathbb{R})$?

Thanks!

Comment: Are the non-real eigenvalues of $A$ complex conjugates?

Comment: @PC1 Yes they are

Comment: Then it means that you can find that matrix $S$.

Comment: @PC1 what is the approach for finding $S$?

Comment: Hint: if $(\lambda, x)$ is a complex eigenpair of $A$, then since $A$ is real, it follows that it has a complex conjugate pair $(\bar{\lambda}, \bar{x})$. Let $u = \frac{x+\bar{x}}{2}, v = \frac{x-\bar{x}}{2i}$, then $A(u~v) = (u~v)B$ with $B = \begin{pmatrix}a&b\\-b&a\end{pmatrix}$ with $\sigma(B) = \{\lambda,\bar{\lambda}\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the only real eigenvalue of $A$ is $1$. Let $v_1$ be a corresponding eigenvector such that $\|v_1\|=1$; you can take, for instance,$$v_1=\left(-\frac1{\sqrt3},\frac1{\sqrt2},\frac1{\sqrt6}\right).$$Now, let $v_2$ be some vector orthogonal to $v_1$ such that $\|v_2\|=1$; you can take, say,$$v_2=\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}},0,\frac2{\sqrt6}\right).$$Finally, let$$v_3=v_1\times v_2=\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},-\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}\right).$$Clearly, $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ is an orthonormal basis of $\Bbb R^3$. Since $v_2$ is orthogonal to $v_1$ and $A$ is an orthogonal matrix, $A.v_2$ is orthogonal to $A.v_1=v_1$. Therefore, $A.v_2$ is a linear combination of $v_2$ and $v_3$. The coefficients of that linear combination are easy to compute:\begin{align}A.v_2&=\langle A.v_2,v_2\rangle v_2+\langle A.v_2,v_3\rangle v_3\\&=\frac35v_2+\frac45v_3.\end{align}Also,$$A.v_3=-\frac45v_2+\frac35v_3,$$and therefore, if$$U=\begin{bmatrix}-\frac1{\sqrt3}&\frac1{\sqrt3}&\frac1{\sqrt3}\\\frac1{\sqrt2}&0&\frac1{\sqrt2}\\\frac1{\sqrt6}&\frac2{\sqrt6}&-\frac1{\sqrt6}\end{bmatrix}$$(the columns of $U$ are the vectors $v_1$, $v_2$, and $v_3$), then$$U^{-1}AU=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&\frac35&-\frac45\\0&\frac45&\frac35\end{bmatrix}.$$So, take\begin{align}S&=U^{-1}\\&=U^T\\&=\begin{bmatrix}-\frac1{\sqrt3}&\frac1{\sqrt2}&\frac1{\sqrt6}\\\frac1{\sqrt3}&0&\frac2{\sqrt6}\\\frac1{\sqrt3}&\frac1{\sqrt2}&-\frac1{\sqrt6}\end{bmatrix}\end{align}and $\theta=-\arccos\left(\frac35\right)$. With this choice of $\theta$, $\cos(\theta)=\frac35$ and $\sin(\theta)=-\frac45$.